# Pass data one function to another function

Tags: python, list

i want to get the insert() function data in find() function.

```
n=int(input("Enter choice: "))

if n==1:
  def insert():
    data=['oop','java','python']
    print(data)
    
    return data

  insert()

elif n==2:
  def find():
    data.insert(1,"hi")
    print(data)

  find()
```

after pressing 2 final output should be

```
 ['oop','hi','java','python']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
n=int(input("Enter choice: "))
data = ['oop', 'java', 'python']
if n==1:
  def insert():
    print(data)
    return data
  insert()

elif n==2:
  def find():
    data.insert(1,"hi")
    print(data)

  find()
```

Output - `['oop', 'hi', 'java', 'python']`

To use list locally:

```
n = int(input("Enter choice: "))

def insert():
    data = ['oop', 'java', 'python']
    return data

def find():
    data = insert()
    data.insert(1, "hi")
    return data

if n==1:
    print(insert())
elif n==2:
    print(find())
```

Output:

```
>> Enter choice: 2
['oop', 'hi', 'java', 'python']
>> Enter choice: 1
['oop', 'java', 'python']
```

Comment: i want to use list locally.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I didn' read your desired output.

Not sure if this is what you need:

```
n=int(input("Enter choice: "))

def insert():
    data=['oop','java','python']
    print(data)
    return data

def find():
   def find():
   data_func = insert()
   data_func.insert(1, "hi")
   print(data_func)

if n==1:
    insert()

elif n==2:
    find()
```

You can't declare funcions inside a conditional "if" since if your input is 2 you will never execute inset() funcion and data variable will never be declared.

Also you should name your functions in different way from python predefined methods...

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how scope works in Python. You can read about it here https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/ but a basic understanding is that variables declared in a function is only local to that function.
What you probably need to do is to pass the data array to both functions to Keep the scope of the variable.